# May I publish hearing documents in a book and on the web?

Tags: copyright, privacy, administrative-law

I have been involved, *pro se*, in a special education impartial hearing on behalf of my son.  I would like to publish some parts of the hearing documents in articles on the web and in a book.  Is that allowed?  Here is a list of all the documents I might like to draw upon (I would redact identifying features and use pseudonyms for names):

- My exhibits, which include my son's educational records, email correspondence with the district, and my hearing request letter
- The hearing transcript *(I contacted the transcription service to see if they mind; the manager is out this week but they will get back to me when she is back)*
- My closing argument
- The district's closing argument
- The hearing officer's decision (which will be posted on the state education department's website in a few months, with our names redacted, but with the name of the hearing officer not redacted)
- My petition of appeal to the state review office, with memorandum of law and the entire email correspondence the district lawyer and I had with the hearing officer as an additional exhibit (note, the district lawyer and I were required to cc each other on all of that correspondence)
- The district's Answer to the state review office, with a memorandum of law
- My Reply to the Answer
- The review officer's decision, which will eventually be posted on the state education department's website

I plan to use pseudonyms for my son and me and the rest of our family.

I noticed that some hearing officer decisions and some review office decisions include last names of district witnesses.  I think that ethically I should omit them, even if the state doesn't redact them.

Answer (score 1):

Many states prohibit revealing the identity of a minor in a proceeding, and you indicate that you would also do so. Otherwise, they are public records and there is generally no prohibition on disclosing them.

Comment: "Would also do so"?  I don't understand.  Are you saying I would also reveal his identity?  Are you saying I would also protect his identity? // Thank you very much for the information about the documents being public records.

Comment: I'm saying you would also redact his identity.